# No FileSystem for scheme: wasbs Apache Zeppelin 0.8.0 with Spark 2.3.2

Tags: azure, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to run note in Apache Zeppelin 0.8.0 with Spark 2.3.2 and Azure Blob Storage, but I'm getting `No FileSystem for scheme: wasbs` error, though I configured all properly, as it is recommended in related issues.
Here are some conf files:

```
spark-defaults.conf
    spark.driver.extraClassPath         /opt/jars/*
    spark.driver.extraLibraryPath       /opt/jars
    spark.jars   /opt/jars/hadoop-azure-2.7.3.jar,/opt/jars/azure-storage-2.2.0.jar
    spark.driver.memory 28669m
```

---

```
core-site.xml
        <configuration>
          <property>         
            <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.wasb.Impl</name>                                 
            <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.Wasb</value> 
          </property>
          <property>
            <name>fs.azure.account.key.{storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net</name>    
            <value>{account_key_value}</value>
          </property>
```

---